# References on non-linear regression analysis

Tags: regression, references, nonlinear-regression, nonlinear

I am looking for the references on non-linear regression analysis. I am mostly interested in introductory textbooks focusing on theory, but covering some applications as well.

Comment: That's a rather vague question. Are you interested in specific applications, theoretical textbooks, or something else?

Comment: Hi Chl, I put this question as I've very little idea on non-linear regression technique. I want to learn it from scratch. The reference I'm looking for is more theoretical, with some application example from any field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend [Gaussian processes for machine learning](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Gaussian-Processes-Machine-Learning-Rasmussen/dp/026218253X) by Rasmussen and Williams and [Nonparametric Regression and Generalized Linear Models: A roughness penalty approach](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Nonparametric-Regression-Generalized-Linear-Models/dp/0412300400) by Green and Silverman.  I've found both books very readable and useful.

Comment: Thanks Dikran! Machine learning book is something I don't think will be very helpful in my field. But the other book look promising. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, Gaussian processes have their roots in statistics (the paper where it is all brought together is by O'Hagen IIRC).  GPs are a very good approach for regression and are essentially the culmination of the roughness penalty approach of Green and Silverman.  You can also download the book for free from their website.

Answer (score 3):

I perused the [Use R!](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387096159) book once.  It didn't look too bad, but I didn't work through it, and I don't use nonlinear regression, either, I was just curious--so take that for what it's worth.  I think if you know a little stats and are comfortable with R already, and want to play around with nonlinear regression, it would be a low-commitment place to start.