# Where to start with nonlinear regression?

Tags: nonlinear-regression

What are some good introductory materials for learning non-linear regression modeling? Bonus points for anything freely available. Thanks!

Comment: non-linear regression is a huge field! You should say something about your preferred application area, which will make it easier to give advice.  A similar question (with answers) http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25608/non-linear-regression-references        http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8570/references-on-numerical-optimization-for-statisticians/10166#10166